# Returning unknown type

Tags: java, generics

Currently I am trying to write a method that returns an unknown object type (serialization). However, I keep getting errors from java demanding I supply a type - but obviously, I do not know what the concrete type of the deserialized object will be.

Here is the code:

```
public static <?> T deSerialize(String path) throws IOException {//Line in question
    try {
        ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));

        return o.readObject();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

I am aware that I could simply return the type `object`, but I would like to know how to do this with generics.

Thanks for any help

Comment: `ObjectInputStream.readObject` returns an Object. If you know the type you can cast it to that type

Comment: You've declared a type variable `T` but your method is not generic -- you can't declare it using the wildcard that way.

Comment: Generics are only for static type checks at compile-time. What you're trying to do (know at compile-time the type of an object whose type is only known at run-time) is not possible and not what generics are for. Also see http://xyproblem.info.

Comment: `public static <T> T deSerialize(String path)` with an unchecked cast to `T` on the return value would make the method "generic", but I don't understand why you'd need this. It wouldn't add any type-safety compile-time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`readObject` method in `ObjectInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject--) returns an `Object` reference to the correct type.

> Read an object from the ObjectInputStream. The class of the object, the signature of the class, and the values of the non-transient and non-static fields of the class and all of its supertypes are read.

...

> Java's safe casting should be used to get the desired type.

So you should just let the caller cast it to the proper type when you call the method.

```
// Non-generic method.
public static Object deSerialize(String path) throws IOException {

// ...
YourType foo = (YourType) deSerialize(path);
```

If you must make it generic, then you must have a type witness, a `Class`, which can perform the dynamically typed cast for you, so that the type can be checked at compile time by the compiler and at run time by [`Class.cast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-).  It's still up to the caller to supply the correct `Class`.

```
public static <T> T deSerialize(String path, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
    try {
        ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));

        return clazz.cast(o.readObject());
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help regettman. Didn't realize that the readObject method handled the obj type that way. Appreciated!